# Expected value of a truncated binomial

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, asymptotics, approximation-theory

Let $X\sim B(n,p)$ be a binomial random variable and fix $0<k<n$.  Are there any well-known bounds for $\mathbb{E} (X-k)^+$, where $(X-k)^+ =\max\{0,X-k\}$?  I am particularly interested in interpreting this as a function of $p\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\vpi{\varphi}$Let 
$$Z_n:=\frac{X_n-np}{\sqrt{npq}},$$
where $X_n:=X$ and $q:=1-p\in(0,1)$. Then $Z_n\to Z\sim N(0,1)$ in distribution (as $n\to\infty$). Also, $EZ_n^2=1$. So,
assuming that 
$$z_{n,k}:=\frac{k-np}{\sqrt{npq}}\to z\in\mathbb R, \tag{0}$$
by the uniform integrability we have 
$$\frac{E(X-k)^+}{\sqrt{npq}}=E(Z_n-z_{n,k})^+
\to E(Z-z)^+,$$
whence 
$$E(X-k)^+\sim\sqrt{npq}\, E(Z-z)^+. \tag{1}$$

---

Also, note that for real $z$
$$\psi(z):=E(Z-z)^+=\int_z^\infty(u-z)\vpi(u)\,du=\vpi(z)-z(1-\Phi(z)),$$
where $\vpi$ and $\Phi$ denote, respectively, the pdf and cdf of $N(0,1)$. Here is the graph $\{(z,\psi(z))\colon|z|<3\}$:

[image]

---

Using more advanced tools than the central limit theorem for the binomial distribution, one can greatly improve estimate (1) (derived assuming (0)). Indeed, by the nonuniform Berry--Esseen bound (see e.g. [formula (4.3.1)](https://books.google.com/books?id=uf6pDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22nonuniform%20Berry--Esseen%20bound%22%20Pinelis&source=bl&ots=ZHKcPv9y1U&sig=ACfU3U08DNv74pm4OtyZCL9GGEZuu7TUJw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifg8an_LPpAhVZbs0KHau1DvgQ6AEwB3oECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22nonuniform%20Berry--Esseen%20bound%22%20Pinelis&f=false)), for all real $t$ 
$$P(Z_n>t)-P(Z>t)=O\Big(\frac1{(1+|t|^3)\sqrt{npq}}\Big). \tag{2}$$
Everywhere here the constants in $O(\cdot)$ are universal. Also, for any real-valued random variable $Y$ and any real $y$,
$$E(Y-y)^+=E\int_y^\infty du\, 1_{Y>u}
=\int_y^\infty du\, P(Y>u).$$
So, by (2),
$$E(X-k)^+=\sqrt{npq}\,E(Z_n-z_{n,k})^+
=\sqrt{npq}\,E(Z-z_{n,k})^+ + O(1). \tag{3}$$
Of course, (3) implies (1) (when (0) holds), but (3) is much stronger and more general than (1).

Comment: That is perfect!  I guess the natural question then becomes "what does $E(Z-z)^+$ look like", although that sounds much more Google-able.

Comment: I have added details on $E(Z-z)^+$ and also added a stronger estimate.

Answer (score 1):

The command of Mathematica 12.0

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[Max[x - k, 0],x\[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n,p]]]
```

produces $${p^{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} (1-p)^{n-\lfloor k\rfloor } \left(-\binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +1;\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)+k \binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +1;\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)-k p \binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +1;\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)+p \binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +1;\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)+p \lfloor k\rfloor  \binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +1;\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)-\lfloor k\rfloor  \binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +1} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +1;\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)-p \binom{n}{\lfloor k\rfloor +2} \, _2F_1\left(2,-n+\lfloor k\rfloor +2;\lfloor k\rfloor +3;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)\right)}{(p-1)^{-2}} $$ for $k\ge 0,\, k <n$.

Comment: Mathematica also finds its variance through `Variance[TransformedDistribution[Max[x - k, 0], 
  x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]]]`.